# Cannot reach the site when using selenium with proxy

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, browser-automation, undetected-chromedriver

When i try to access a random website via undetected-chromedriver with proxy configured. Using the code below:

```
from time import sleep
import json
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chromium.service import ChromiumService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

service = ChromiumService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

config = json.load(open('config.json','r'))

def checker(proxy):

    opts = Options()
    opts.binary_location = config['chrome-path']
    opts.add_argument("--proxy-server=" + "\"" + proxy + "\"")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(version_main=110, options=opts, service=service)
    sleep(5)

    driver.get('https://whatismyip.com')
    sleep(100)

checker('IP:PORT')
```

The `config.json` have nothing special:

```
{
    "chrome-path": "/bin/ungoogled-chromium"
}
```

The result is that my browser cannot reach any given website.
[image]

When launching chromium manually via commandline `ungoogled-chromium --proxy-server="IP:PORT"` (with the same ip of course) all the site load as normal.
I also try [seleniumwire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) but it also not work.
I hope to find any possible cause and way to fix. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to proxy to a site while using undetected-chromedriver mode.

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run this with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, proxy="IP:PORT") as sb:
    sb.driver.get("https://whatismyip.com")
    sb.sleep(10)
```